# (Java) How do you make a program only create one frame when you press a Jbutton regardless of how many times you press it?

Tags: for-loop, jframe, actionlistener

how do you stop your program from generating JFrames after you press a JButton? I am trying to make it stop generating new JFrames after the first button press but sadly, this isn't happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
list.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        for (int counter=0; counter<1; counter++){
                    if (counter<1){
                        Newbox fresh = new Newbox();
                            }
                                if (counter >1) {
                                break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a boolean variable to stop it from creating a new frame. something like

```
boolean pressed = false;
list.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
    for (int counter=0; counter<1; counter++){
                if (counter<1 && pressed == false){
                    Newbox fresh = new Newbox();
                    pressed = true;
                        }
                            if (counter >1) {
                            break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I think the for loop can be removed, because it will run only once anyway and I think the OP tried to solve his problem like this.

Answer (score 0):

Trx to add a boolean.

```
Boolean pressed = false;

list.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)   {
        if (!pressed){
            Newbox fresh = new Newbox();
            pressed = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Note: The Boolean has to be _outside_ the method, a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using booleans but this approach ended up working better so for the record, this is one way to solve this. Thank you all for the feedback.

```
           list.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
                        Newbox fresh = new Newbox();
                            ((AbstractButton)e.getSource()).setEnabled(false);

                    } 
                });
```